# How do I remove the first occurrence of a value from a vector?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to get a single element from a vector and push it to the back of the vector then remove it so I won't have an empty section in memory. The erase-remove idiom can do this but it removes *all* instances of a particular value. I just want the first one removed.

I'm not too experienced with standard library algorithms and I can't find the appropriate methods (if any) to do this. Here is an example:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 3, 4};

    remove_first(v, 3);

    std::cout << v; // 1, 2, 3, 4
}
```

So how would I go about removing the first occurance of a 3 from this vector?

Comment: What's wrong with find(v.begin(), v.end(), 3) and then erasing that iterator?

Comment: Do you care about the order of elements in the `vector`?  If not, `swap`-`erase` works great.

Comment: @Yakk I like the idea (maybe add it as an answer?), but I think since OP is asking how to delete the *first* 3 in his container, he kind of does care about the order :)

Comment: @us2012 that assumes that the question is asking what the person needs to know.  As an example, maybe they don't care if it is the first, but they only want to remove 1 of them.  "Remove only the first" does this as well, and if they didn't know that not caring about order makes their problem easier, they might not know that it matters they don't care...

Comment: @us2012 No I meant the first number that is a 3. Did you know what I meant when I said that? I didn't mean the first three elements.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, too. Change "the first 3" into "the first occurence of 3" in my earlier comment, that makes it clear.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Find it first, then erase it:

```
auto it = std::find(v.begin(),v.end(),3);
// check that there actually is a 3 in our vector
if (it != v.end()) {
  v.erase(it);
}
```

Comment: Note: Erasing an element from a vector sucks. All the elements after the erased elements need to be copied back 1 element. Erasing from a `list` is _much_ cheaper

Comment: @Dave True, but the choice of data structure depends on more than that. If you erase a lot, this is a concern, but often you only erase a few times but access indexed elements all the time, which sucks for lists.

Comment: @Dave: Probably not, actually. Lists don't play well with cache. You can *make* them live well with cache, but it's not easier than using vector until profiling says to do otherwise.

Comment: Erase from a list is O(1), but finding the element in the list is O(n). The combined find/erase operation is O(n) for vector and list both - and as we all know, vector's constants tend to be *substantially* smaller than list's.

Answer (score 11):

If you don't care about maintaining the ordering of the elements in the vector, you can avoid the copy of the "tail" of remaining elements on erase:

```
auto it = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), 3);
if (it != v.end()) {
  std::iter_swap(it, v.end() - 1);
  v.erase(v.end() - 1);
}
```

Comment: Nice Solution :-)
Since I just want to remove first occurrence of an element because my vector holds no duplicates I did not like std::forward_list::remove.
This seem to me currently the best solution.