# Removing element from the standard list

Tags: c++

Suppose I have the following class

```
class Human
 {
public:
    Human();
    Human(string,int);
    virtual ~Human();
    string getName();

protected:

private:
    string name;
    int staj;
 };
```

I have created list with 2 elements that I pushed in

```
  list<Human> mylist;
  Human x ("Mike",13);
  Human y("pavlek",33);
```

I am trying to remove if there is element with name "Mike",I tried removing it like this :

```
   for(list<Human>::iterator it=mylist.begin();it!=mylist.end();++it)
  {


  if(it->getName()=="Mike")
  {
      mylist.remove(it);
      cout<< "removed";
       cout<<it->getName();
  }
```

}

However I get error at passing the value to the `remove()` function,what should I exactly pass in order to delete this element from the list?

Comment: Consider using `<algorithm>` and the `erase`-`remove_if` idiom: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39019806/using-erase-remove-if-idiom But if you don't, then at least cache your `end()` iterator! ;-) Alternatively, this answer shows a nicer way using `<algorithm>` to remove just the 1st matching element, if that's all you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737780/how-do-i-remove-the-first-occurrence-of-a-value-from-a-vector

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866642/stl-list-erase-items

Answer (score 2):

You have simply mistaken `erase` and `remove`. According to the C++ reference, `remove` is used to [remove from the list all elements whose values are equals to the given parameter](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/remove/). On the other hand, `erase` [removes a single element given its position or a range of elements given the start and end positions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/erase/).

If you only need to delete the first element containing `"Mike"` as its name, simply do something like this:

```
for(list<Human>::iterator it=mylist.begin();it!=mylist.end();++it)
{
    if(it->getName() == "Mike")
    {
        mylist.erase(it);
        break;
    }
}
```

Please notice that [after using erase, your iterator will be invalidated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433164/what-happens-to-an-stl-iterator-after-erasing-it-in-vs-unix-linux). You can circumvent it by using the returned value of `erase`, which is the next valid iterator value. This detail is important if your list might contain multiple elements whose name is `"Mike"`.

Comment: just to reiterate (pardon the pun) this code will not work. The iterator is invlaid after the erase

Answer (score 0):

Matheus Portela's solution was the old C++98 method. It's a lot easier now:

```
mylist.remove_if( [](Human const& h){return h.getName()=="Mike";} );
```

The condition here is `[](Human const& h){return h.getName()=="Mike";}`. That is a lambda expression which returns true if the `Human h` should be removed. You can test any other property or combination of properties there. The `{ }` part of the lambda is a real function body; you could even have for-loops in there:

Other examples:

```
mylist.remove_if( [](Human const& h){return h.getName().size() > 4; } );

mylist.remove_if( [](Human const& h) {
     for (char c: h.getName())
         if (c=='i') return true; // remove if name contains an i
     return false; } );
```

Mind you, the latter would be easier with `std::any_of`.