# erase a specific value from a vector array

Tags: c++, vector

```
ara[2].erase(std::remove(ara[2].begin(), ara[2].end(), 4), ara[2].end());
```

This code erase all the value which are exactly 4 from the vector.But I want to erase only the first value which is 4 and after that rest 4 are not.If the 4 doesn't exist in the vector at all so not to erase any.how to do that? please help me.I need the minimum time complexity also.

Comment: Looks like an A/B problem to me

Comment: @rosudel As for me then it is unclear what you are trying to do. Could you provide sample data and the expected result?

Comment: if ara[2] = {2,6,5,8,7,9,6,4,5,6,6,6} is a vector then I want to delete only one  6 from the vector if found, otherwise need not to delete any.so the output should be,
ara[2] = {2,5,8,7,9,6,4,5,6,6,6}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737780/how-do-i-remove-the-first-occurrence-of-a-value-from-a-vector